# UIDragInteractionDelegate Check if Drag Failed

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, ios11

The `UIDragInteractionDelegate` class has a callback for when the session ends:

`func dragInteraction(UIDragInteraction, session: UIDragSession, didEndWith: UIDropOperation)`

However, this doesn't seem to get called if the user cancels the drag, i.e. drops the items on something that doesn't have an attached `UIDropInteraction`. Is there any way to get a callback when this happens?

Comment: Late to the party: You may want to check out `dragInteraction:item:willAnimateCancelWith)`. It is supposed to be called when the drag is cancelled. I did not test it though.

Answer (score -1):

i used the following methods to check for failure of Drag session

func dragInteraction(UIDragInteraction, session: UIDragSession, didEndWith: UIDropOperation)

here UIDropOperation tells you what operation is done by DropInteraction

eg:

if UIDropOperation == .copy // the drop operation have selected copy

similarly for move, cancel and forbidden

you can also use the following function "sessionDidTransferItems" ,

is called when drop session is successful otherwise this function is not called

hope this info helps